# Wait until NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest is finished

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following problem. I have a Model, called User. When the user now logins with Facebook, my app checks if the user exists already in the database. To not freeze the UI (since I'm coming from Android) I thought to use `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest`. What worked at first was the following:

My User Model had a method to do the whole task of the `AsynchronousRequest` and then when finished would set a variable to loading. Then other classes, could simply check with 
`while ( !user.loading )` if the Request was finished or not. The problem that came here to me, was, that now, I had to put this method in every Model. So instead of this, I created a new Class `HTTPPost`. This class now has the method that gets an `NSDictionary` passed and returns one. This works ALMOST. The problem I was now encountering is, that I couldn't really determine if the process was finished or not. So I started to create a new class called `Globals` and use global Variable `loading`. But the global variable is ALWAYS NO. So, what would be the best way to do this?

Here is my code:

This is where I check for the user and load it. `resultDictionary` is the `NSDictionary` where everything gets loaded in, but is always `nil`

```
 [user loadModelFrom:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"WHERE facebookId='%@'", graphUser.id]];
        NSLog(@"%@", user.resultDictionary);
        if ( user.resultDictionary == nil ) {
            NSLog(@"NIL");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"NOT NIL");
        }
```

The problem now, is, that, since I'm sending an AsynchronousRequest, the resultDictionary is always nil. What I did before and worked was the following.

In my Model I had the HTTP Request and a variable named `loading`. Now I set loading to false until the response has been made into a `NSDictionary`

```
returnDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [responseBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                   options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                     error: &error];
```

But, then I had another problem. I had to do this in all my Models again... So I created a new Class that subclasses NSObject, that has the asynchronousRequest. This is the whole request

```
-(NSDictionary *)doHttpRequest:(NSDictionary *)postDict{
    loading = NO;
    __block NSDictionary *returnDict;
    NSError *error;
    NSString *jsonString;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                         error:&error];

    if (! jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
    } else {
        jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xx-xx.xx/xx.xx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"xx", @"xx"];
    NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedString]];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         returnDict             = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [responseBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                   options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                     error: &error];

     }];
    [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
    loading = YES;
    return returnDict;
}
```

As you can see I have now a variable called `loading`. It is a global variable. But somehow, the variable is always NO.

What would be the best way to do this? I hope I'm understandable, I'm new to Objective-C, and English isn't my native language.

**UPDATE**

I modified the code to look like a user provided here, but still not working!

```
HTTPPost.h
-(void)doHttpRequest:(NSDictionary *)postDict completion:(void(^)(NSDictionary *dict, NSError *error))completion {
    __block NSDictionary *returnDict;
    NSError *error;
    NSString *jsonString;
    NSString *authValue;
    NSString *authStr;

    NSData *jsonData;
    NSData *authData;
    NSURL *aUrl;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request;
    NSOperationQueue *queue;


    jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];

    if (! jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
    } else {
        jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    aUrl        = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xx-xx.com/xx.php"];
    request     = [NSMutableURLRequest  requestWithURL:aUrl
                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                           timeoutInterval:60.0];

    queue       = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    authStr     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"xx", @"xx"];
    authData    = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    authValue   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedString]];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         returnDict             = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [responseBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                  options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                    error: &error];
         if ( completion ) {
             completion(returnDict, error);
         }
     }];
}

//User.h
[_httpPost doHttpRequest:_dbDictionary completion:^(NSDictionary *dict, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"completed") // NEVER GETS FIRED
}];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to take an asynchronous process (`sendAsynchronousRequest`) , and make it behave like a synchronous process (i.e. you appear to want to wait for it). You should not do that. You should to embrace the asynchronous patterns rather than fighting them.

The `sendAsynchronousRequest` method has a completion block that specifies what you want to do when the request is done. Do not try to put the code *after* the block and (try to) wait for the block to complete, but rather put any of your code that is dependent upon the completion of the network request *inside* the completion block, or have the completion block call your code.

A common way would be to give your own methods their own completion blocks and then call those blocks in the `completionHandler` of `sendAsynchronousRequest`, something like:

```
- (void)performHttpRequest:(NSDictionary *)postDict completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error))completion
{
    // prepare the request

    // now issue the request

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            if (completion)
                completion(data, error);
        } else {
            NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            returnDict             = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                     options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                      error: &error];
            if (completion)
                completion(returnDict, error);
    }];
}
```

Now, when you want to perform your request, you simply do:

```
[self performHttpRequest:someDictionary completion:^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // ok, handle the error here
    } else {
        // ok, use the `dictionary` results as you see fit here
    }
];
```

Note, the method that calls this `performHttpRequest` (let's imagine you called it from `loadModelFrom` ) now behaves asynchronously, itself. So you might want to employ this completion-block pattern again, e.g. adding your own `completion` block parameter to `loadModelFrom`, and then invoke that block in the completion handler `loadModelFrom` passes to `performHttpRequest`.

But hopefully you get the idea: Never try to wait for a completion block, but rather just put inside that block anything you want it to do when its done. Whether you use AFNetworking (which I'd advise), or continue to use `sendAsynchronousRequest`, this is a very useful pattern with which you should become familiar.

---

**Update:**

The revised code sample (largely) works great for me. Seeing your revised question, a couple of observations:

1. I am not familiar with this `base64EncodedString` method. In iOS 7, there is the native `base64EncodedStringWithOptions` method (or for earlier iOS versions use `base64Encoding`). Or are you using a third party base-64 `NSData` category?
2. There's no point in creating `jsonString`, only to then convert it back to a `NSData`. Just use `jsonData` in your request.

   The same is true with `responseBody`: Why convert to string only to convert back to `NSData`?
3. There's no point in having `returnDict` to be defined as `__block` outside the `sendAsynchronousRequest` block. Just define it inside that block and the `__block` qualifier is then no longer necessary.
4. Why create a `NSOperationQueue` for the `completionHandler` of `sendAsynchronousRequest`? Unless I'm doing something really slow that merits running on a background queue, I just use `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`, because you invariably want to update the app's model or UI (or both), and you want to do that sort of stuff on the main queue.

   The request still runs asynchronously but the `queue` parameter just specifies which queue the completion block will run on.
5. By the way, in `sendAsynchronousRequest`, you aren't checking to see if the request succeeded before proceeding with `JSONObjectWithData`. If the request failed, you could theoretically be losing the `NSError` object that it returned. You really should check to make sure the request succeeded before you try to parse it.

   Likewise, when you originally `dataWithJSONObject` the parameters in `postDict`, you really should check for success, and if not, report the error and quit.
6. I notice that you're using the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option. If you really need a mutable response, I'd suggest making that explicit in your block parameters (replacing all the `NSDictionary` references with `NSMutableDictionary`). I assume you don't really need it to be mutable, so I therefore recommend removing the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option.

   Likewise, when creating the JSON, you don't need to use the `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` option. It only makes the request unnecessary larger.

Combining all of this, that yields:

```
-(void)performHttpRequest:(NSDictionary *)postDict completion:(void(^)(NSDictionary *dict, NSError *error))completion {
    NSError *error;
    NSString *authValue;
    NSString *authStr;

    NSData *jsonData;
    NSData *authData;
    NSURL *aUrl;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request;

    jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict options:0 error:&error];

    if (!jsonData) {
        if (completion)
            completion(nil, error);
        return;
    }

    aUrl        = [NSURL URLWithString:@"...."];
    request     = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];

    authStr     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"xx", @"xx"];
    authData    = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if ([authData respondsToSelector:@selector(base64EncodedStringWithOptions:)])
        authValue   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
    else
        authValue   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64Encoding]]; // if only supporting iOS7+, you don't need this if-else logic and you can just use base64EncodedStringWithOptions
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!data) {
             if (completion)
                 completion(nil, error);
             return;
         }

         NSError *parseError = nil;
         NSDictionary *returnDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

         if (completion) {
             completion(returnDict, parseError);
         }
     }];
}
```

And if this is being called from another method that needs to handle the fact that this is happening asynchronously, then it would employ a completion block pattern, too:

```
- (void)authenticateUser:(NSString *)userid password:(NSString *)password completion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ ... };

    [self performHttpRequest:dictionary completion:^(NSDictionary *dict, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            completion(NO);
            return;
        }

        // now validate login by examining resulting dictionary

        BOOL success = ...;

        // and call this level's completion block

        completion(success);
    }];
}
```

Then the view controller might access that method with something like:

```
// maybe add UIActivityIndicatorView here

[self.userModel authenticateUser:self.userTextField.text password:self.passwordTextField.text completion:^(BOOL success) {
    // remove UIActivityIndicatorView here
    if (success) {
        // do whatever you want if everything was successful, maybe segue to another view controller
    } else {
        // show the user an alert view, letting them know that authentication failed and let them try again
    }
}];
```

Comment: Hi, I'm at home now, but this seems to be a good way to do. I will try it out tomorrow and then tell you how it went, but It sounds like it would be a good one!

Comment: Hi @Rob - Unfortunaely this isn't working. I modified my initial post, so now you can see how it is at the moment and it doesn't really work.

Comment: @Musterknabe When you say "doesn't really work", what happens? I just tested your code against my server (only replacing the base-64 method) and it worked fine. I'd suggest setting a breakpoint and single stepping through your code and figure out where it went wrong. If it's not crashing, but you're not seeing it complete, the only thing I can imagine is if your _httpPost variable was not properly instantiated. But the code works fine. If it did crash, update your question and tell us precisely what happened. See my revised answer for some detailed observations on your code.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't see you answered... I'm really sorry. Well the problem is the following. I made 3 `NSLog`-outputs. One after the method is called, one after the completion block is reached in the `sendAsynchronousRequest` and one in the `completion callback`. The problem is, that the one after the method get always called first. But I need the result of the request before continuing with the app. How do I do that?

Comment: @Musterknabe Understood. But, why do you need the response before returning? Why not employ your own completion block pattern? Don't worry that you're seeing the log after the completion block first: Just put any code you need to run after the asynchronous task _inside_ the completion block!

Comment: Hi, I can tell you why :)

I have a `UIViewController` that handles the authentication process of the application. So in this `UIViewController` I have the logic implemented to check the authentication status of the user with this app and Facebook. So, now I check in the application if the user is already in the database. To do this, I have a class `loadModelFrom` in my `User`-class. This method however calls the method for the HTTPRequest. Im doing this, because I have multiple models and I don't want to rewrite the method every time, so I have a central HTTPHandler file that handles requests

Comment: This means, that the flow is the following  

1. `UIViewController` -> Check for user in DB by calling  
2. `User`-model to load a Model and call
3. `HTTPPost`-class to check. So the completion block works from HTTPPost to the User-Model, but not from the User-Model to the ViewController. I hope I made it understandable. :)

Comment: @Musterknabe Nothing that you describe precludes following this standard asynchronous pattern of completion blocks (or, if you want to go old-school, delegate patterns). From each layer (view controller to user model, user model to network request and/or db, etc.) can just employ the same sort of asynchronous completion block parameter pattern. But having the view controller ever block the main queue is never going to be the right solution.

Comment: Hi. I'm coming from Android and developing for both systems at the same time is a bit confusing for me, so sorry for my misunderstanding.

How exactly could I use the completion block when calling a method from the HTTPPost from the UserModel from the UIViewController?

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I have been killing myself to understand how this works to call an async method and then to handle the data when it comes back.  Your code was exactly what I needed of course I should just call the completion block when the async thread is done.  Makes total sense now.

Comment: Hi, I am implementing a very similar code. My view calls a User that calls the HTTP request. I have completion blocks working and a lot of NSLog to check the process. The thing is that all logs are printed within 1 second, including the ones from the view, but my view is not updated until 40 seconds have passed. I have two consecutive lines for printing and changing a label and the text is printed but the label is not changed. What can be the reason for that?

Comment: A common source of that problem is a failure to dispatch those UI updates back to the main queue. All UI updates must happen on main thread. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

After seeing you adding specific code to handle request and its responses, I would point out that you should try using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). It abstracts out lots of boiler plate code.

As you mentioned, you are new to obj-c, it may take some time to understand AFNetworking but in long run, it will save you lots of headache. Plus it is one of the widely used open source for network related stuff.

I hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for a request, then you should not use sendAsynchronousRequest.
Use sendSynchonousRequest instead. That's where it's made for:

```
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError * error;    
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

But, the UI is blocked when the synchronous call is made. I doubt if that is what you want.