# NSURLConnection stuck after timeout

Tags: ios, timeout, nsurlconnection

I got a problem with NSURLConnection and spent more than 3 days to find a solution
but unfortunately, i haven't get one. 
Here is my code, this is in a dedicated class and use completehandler to return

```
    NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:targetSite];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                          timeoutInterval:timeOutInterval];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:MYBODYCONTENT];
    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    if(conn)
    {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
```

and use delegate to receive data, it works fine in "didReceiveResponse", "didReceiveData", "didFailWithError", "connectionDidFinishLoading", ...

BUT, if a request timeout happend, (i already did [conn cancel] in "didFailWithError")
then, in a peroid of time (I didn't do a precise count but about 1 min)
All my new request to the same server(request again) will be timeout again and again.
Is there anything I do wrong?
Or anything I should modify my code?
I have tried lots of solutions but still no go.
So, looking for some help, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there is no problem in connecting to the server. It maybe som e issue with your network or the server you are connecting to. If the request is timing out, you may want to wait more than a minute to retry the same request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common problem is that if you initiate many `NSURLConnection` requests, it can only run a certain number concurrently (usually 4 or 5). So, if you initiate more than that, it can only run a few of them at a time, and all the others will get backlogged, waiting until one of the slots becomes available. Sadly, if this takes more than a minute, the latter requests can timeout.

One solution to this is to wrap your `NSURLConnection` objects in custom `NSOperation` subclass. Then rather than just starting the connections all at once, you can add them to a `NSOperationQueue`, letting the operation queue decide when to start them. So, if you define that queue's `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to be 4 or 5, then the operation queue will not try to start them all at the same time, solving the `NSURLConnection` timeout problem.

For background regarding how to subclass `NSOperation` for concurrent operation, see *Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution* section of the [Concurrency Programming Guide: Operation Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24943851/1271826 for a demonstration of wrapping `NSURLConnection` objects in `NSOperation` subclass.

Even better, if you don't want to get lost in the details here, consider using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), which uses an operation queue solution (for `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, at least). Just make sure to set the manager's operation queue's `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to, say 4, and then one can add as many network operations as desired, and the operation queue will ensure they won't timeout.